# Android soft keyboard replaces newlines by spaces while entering text, why?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am using Android 11 and when the soft keyboard comes up it does not break the line when I press enter. Instead, it shows the new lines as spaces. However, when I press "Done" the new line shows correctly on the edittext box.

Is there a setting I need to do to make the softkey to allow line breaks to show up correctly? My edittext has the multi-line properties set correctly. This seems to be how the soft keyboard works.

Here a snipped of my edittext, I set the multi-line flag programmatically.

```
editView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL |
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE |
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
editView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Now if I enter the text below (5 linefeeds)

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

This is what the soft keyboard shows (shows LF as a space):

[image]

When I press enter the text looks correct:

[image]

Is there a way to make the softkey board break the line as we edit? This is running on a generic samsung phone.

thank you.

Comment: The android soft keyboard doesn't do this.  Some particular keyboard might, but the framework doesn't.  But if so, that's a bug in that keyboard, or in the app displaying it.

Comment: I'd  put a breakpoint in InputConnection.commitText and see if its actually sending a \n or a space.

Comment: @GabeSechan I don't understand. I tested this code in three different devices. The softkey is always doing this. You are saying it is a bug on the samsung keyboard? I doubt it.

Comment: I'm saying I wrote keyboards for a living for 3 years.  The framework does NOT do this.  It's either a bug in the Samsung keyboard, or in the display.  Which I can't tell, you'd need to see what data is actually sent over the input connection.